# Why this while loop just keeps going instead of stopping?

Tags: python, while-loop

When I press "y" in the first question the loop just keeps going instead of stopping.

```
Done = True
while Done:
quit = str(raw_input ("Do you want to quit? "))
if quit == 'y' :
Done=False;
attack = str(raw_input("Does your elf attack the dragon? "))
if attack=='y':
print ("Bad choice, you died.")
done=False;
print "Loop stopped"
```

I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Please indent it correctly.

Comment: First thing that's wrong:  indentation.  Second thing that smells wrong: You're using `print` as a function, but `raw_input` - one is a Python 3.x function, the other is a Python 2.x function.  Which version are you using?

Comment: Case matters, `Done` is not the same as `done`. Also, `;` are not required in Python. And as mentioned, whitespace matters, so your indentation needs to be correct.

Comment: @Dana: I corrected the indentation, please make sure it's correct.

Comment: @l19: Your edit ***completely*** changed the question; I've rolled it back.

Comment: The question needs improvements and corrections. In this form, it is hard understand and see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is case-sensitive. You need to make sure `Done` is always capitalized or not:

```
>>> Done = True
>>> while Done:
    quit = str(raw_input ("Do you want to quit? "))
    if quit == 'y' :
        Done = False
    attack = str(raw_input("Does your elf attack the dragon? "))
    if attack=='y':
        print("Bad choice, you died.")
        Done = False
        print("Loop stopped")
```

As Makoto has pointed out, in Python 2.x, the parentheses in the print statements above are a grouping mechanism. But in Python 3.x, `print` constitutes a function and requires parentheses. The above code will work in both versions of Python.

Comment: That's pretty good - I didn't even notice the variable being lower case there.  It doesn't address the inconsistency with print being treated as a function, but this is a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @Makoto. I made the print statements consistent.

Comment: wow thank you...lot of things I didnt know here

Comment: Be careful - they were consistent with respect to OP's code, but the answer here doesn't address that you could just use `from __future__ import print_function` to be consistent with Python 3.x, and use `print` as a function instead.  Also, who downvoted this answer?  This is the only one that actually addresses the *problem* with the code.  Very confusing.

Comment: @Makoto I believe a simple print('test string') works for both Python 2.x and 3.x, without importing from future. I opted for the parentheses to make these statements compatible with both Python 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: Your `elif attack=='y':` doesn't line up with an `if`. It's unclear how this would work.

Comment: @Johnsyweb Thanks for catching that. I accidentally modified the indentation later.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use a `break`, this is used to stop a loop:

```
while True:
    quit = str(raw_input ("Do you want to quit? "))
    if quit == 'y' :
        break  # Add this
    ...
```

Quoting [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html):

> The break statement, like in C, breaks out of the smallest enclosing for or while loop.

**Edit:**

You could try using an infinite loop (`while True`) and when you want to exit it, just check for a condition and use a `break` statement.

Comment: The boolean variable is being changed to `False`.  That's checked at the top of the loop.  Why would adding "break" fix the issue if the boolean controlling the loop should work (pending correct indentation)?